# Angularjs - Single Page Application Not Rendering Page Templates

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, single-page-application

So I was trying to make a SPA using angular but when I try to open my page on a localhost the navbar displays but none of the content I have in separate HTML documents loads. I feel as if I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

### HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="App"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--External Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Internal Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- External Scripts -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/anime.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a1dcc6967b.js"></script>

    <!-- Internal Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var CSStransforms = anime({
            targets: '#CSStransforms .el',
            translateX: 250,
            scale: 2,
            rotate: '1turn'
        });

    </script>

    <title>Bootsrap Shell With Navabar</title>

</head><body ng-controller="mainController">        
      <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">

        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/Page-Name">Page</a>
                </li>
                <!-- Dropdown - Delete from this comment to the next if you don't want it -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separted</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown user">

                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Signed in as </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Log Out</a>
                    </div>

                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>

    <div id="login-modal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="login-modal-container">
                <form id="login-form" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2 class="modal-text">Login To Your Account </h2>
                        <div id="err-msg"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" class="form-control input-lg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-lg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="captcha"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Press To Sign In" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer modal-text">
                        Don't have an account? <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">Sign Up here</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
App.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

App.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

App.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

### Edit

Bower was used to get angular

```
{"name": "site","authors": ["Luculent"],"description": "","main":"index.php","license": "MIT","homepage": "/","ignore": ["**/.*","node_modules","bower_components","test","tests"]}
```

### Edit 2

got angular 1.6.3 but still does not work

### Edit 3

when I launch the page it generates the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=App&p1=Error%3A%20%…%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A44)
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:42
at p (angular.min.js:7)
at g (angular.min.js:41)
at eb (angular.min.js:46)
at c (angular.min.js:21)
at Pc (angular.min.js:22)
at ue (angular.min.js:20)
at angular.min.js:332
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

But as you can see above I have both angular.js and angular-route.

Comment: open the developer console does it output anything? or no errors

Comment: also if thoes controllers are all in one file you can chain our App.controller('asdf').controller('asdf2').config().service.filter etc

Comment: Can you also add the full html file to show the script referrences ? Also your console entries are not visible here

Comment: btw i ran your code and its working for me actually

Comment: might be my web server

Comment: is your ` AngularJS Route module` is correct ..?

Comment: [$injector:modulerr] errors are because you didnt include the js file for that module i am assuming its for the ngRoute becaues thats the only module you included in your angular.app line

Comment: Can you please add the opening html and bidy tag ?

Comment: done sorry for the trouble that caused

Comment: Would using PHP alongside angular cause some sort of error? As I am also using PHP for some back-end stuff.

Comment: Is this line supposed to be in the html  <?php } ?>

Comment: yes. That is a php piece that I forgot to take out

Comment: No `ng-app`? Also, why include both `anime.min.js` and `anime.js`?

Comment: anime.js isn't in anymore. realised that I still had it there while writing this

Comment: Also, *"Unexpected token `import` in angular.min.js"* suggests you've grabbed Angular v2 instead of Angular v1.

Comment: I may have. Would it have done that if I used bower to get it?

Comment: Depends what your `bower.json` looks like

Comment: does that help @Phil

Comment: The problem here is it's not serving the HTML files via URL . He has to fix his wamp64 sever to return HTML

Answer (score 1):

**did you include angular route**

Its no longer included into angularjs by default

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: yes the injector error in console also shows that !

Comment: I do have angular route imported but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Please try removing ngRoute tag from below line

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);
```

You are already providing $routeProvider here

Comment: still outputs the same in my console and no content as usual

Comment: Try requesting the html pages inidividually from the server from url. Looks like PHP is not serving the html static files

Comment: I'm able to get them in my browser from the file dir but not on my site. I even changed the index.php document to HTML and that doesn't work. So it isn't a PHP issue. Even using localhost/pages/filename I can get them

Comment: Yes you are right you have to fix the apache server to serve static content properly

Comment: As I'm running wamp64 how would I go about this? I'm sure it's simple.